# Pretty URLs with hashes (md5)

Tags: hash, md5

In our web application we display a list of pulses, but for linking and such we make every pulse uniquely available. In our Couch DB we are giving every pulse a unique id by md5'ing their unique attributes. I.E.: www.foo.com/bar/

Though these md5 sums are extremely long and make for ugly URLs. Is there another way to hash the attributes that will require less characters but still guarantee uniqueness.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating an ugly `md5` you could use a method [like this](http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/php-code/php-random-string-with-numbers-and-letters/) to create a `random string` of a `given length` containing `certain characters` and insert this into a row next to the `md5` row that is used for retrieving the data from the database using the 'pretty url' string. One thing to think about would be to take out the vowels from the possible characters as with them, you could end up with bad words :) Also, make sure it does not already exist in the database of course, and if it does just create another one... that won't happen very often though.

Comment: But wouldn't it be highly probable that two id's overlap... there will be hundreds of thounsands of pulses (hopefully)

Comment: Not really - say there are 10 digits and 26 letters possible to form your unique, pretty url and you want it to be 5 characters long, I think that there are 36^5 possible permutations. Giving you very little chance of collision. Please check my math though :)

Comment: And it would make sense to check for that id before creating a new one, actually that works well, thanks